# How to logout in rest_framework with JWT authentication?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, logout

How to log out in rest_framework?
This is my user serializer. I'm using rest and very very newbie. Sign up and Login working, but have no clue how to impelement logout.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'password', 'email')
        write_only_fields = ('username', 'email', 'password',)
        read_only_fields = ('id', )
```

Sign up part

```
class UserCreateAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
```

Loggin code; i am using JWT authentication.

```
path(r'login/', obtain_jwt_token, name='ObtainJWTToken'),
```

When i use this code:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def logout(request):
    request.auth.delete()
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

i get error: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'delete'
When i use Djoser code:

```
permission_classes = settings.PERMISSIONS.token_destroy

    def post(self, request):
        utils.logout_user(request)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

getting this error: type object 'Token' has no attribute 'objects'

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use `TokenAuthentication`.

In this case, give this method a shot:

```
class LogoutAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        request.user.auth_token.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

However, please note that this deletes the token and consequently forces a logout.

In case you use `SessionAuthentication`, the body  of your  `get()` method inside the  `LogoutAPIView` class could be just `logout(request)`.

eg.

```
def get(self, request):
    logout(request)
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

In the case of JWT authentication, as it is stateless and each JWT token is valid for some time, that means even if you remove the token from the DB, the user will still be able to use your endpoints for a short amount of time, until it's expired. 
Therefore, depending on how deep you want to go, you can eg. implement a "tokens_unable_to_login" cache key and check if the requests include a JWT token that should not log in. Or you let it expire - you can toy around with the expiration time of the token and see what's ideal for your use-case. That's up to your business requirements.

Let me know how did this go for you.

Comment: updated my response to include some thought  on  the JWT  case

Comment: It's university project i don't need to make accomplish it perfectly.
Therefore, depending on how deep you want to go, you can eg. implement a "tokens_unable_to_login" cache key and check if the requests include a JWT token that should not log in. As i told, i hardly understand Djano(rest) coding. I'll be gratefull, if you will help with coding. Thank you for reply

Comment: Understood! The `LogoutAPIView` class implementation I provided in the response will work for you :)  Just copy it and you should be ok.